# Come and save us vs Come to save us

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, difference

**Bad guy:** *Nobody can save you.*

**Good guy:** *Yes, there is. Alex, he'll come and/to save us.*

Could anyone please explain to me what the difference is between using **and** and **to** in this context, if there is any? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

He'll come to save us. is merely using a to-infinitive. The purpose of his coming is to save us.

Like: He came to see us.

He'll come and save us. There are two actions: He will come and he will save us.

Like: He came and told us. Two actions.

**The stylistic focus is different in them.** One emphasizes purposes and the other the actions.

Comment: Result vs intention. If she came and hit me, then she hit me. Ouch. If she came to hit me, she might have hit me, or (I hope), I might have dodged the blow, or hidden, or simply not been at home.